# spring integration dsl buffer

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a requirement where I need to hold/buffer the messages that are received on a channel and persist in database based on number of messages or timeout mean no messages received for 1min.
Is there a way to achieve this in spring integration

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .destination(sourceQueue))
                .transform(someTransform, "transform")
                .handle(someService, "save")
                .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `.aggregate()` operator based on the `Aggregator` EI-pattern implementation.

That one you can configure with the `JdbcMessageStore` to buffer messages and store them into DB.

You can hold them there until some condition via `ReleaseStrategy` (based on each message arriving) or release them due to `group timeout`.

If you are not interested to have them all afterward as a single aggregated message, you can consider to use a `SimpleMessageGroupProcessor` which just produces a `Collection<Message<?>>` and iterates over them to send to the output one by one.

See more info about aggregator in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator

Comment: We want to accumulate message without correlationId, we are seeing the following error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?` with this change `.aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec.releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() > 2))`

Comment: You can do a static correlationKey: `.correlationStrategy(m -> 1)`. Also you need to ensure an `expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)`.

Comment: Thanks `.aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec.correlationStrategy(m -> 1).expireGroupsUponCompletion(true).releaseStrategy(new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(2, 100)))` worked

Comment: the above didnt work without `.expireGroupsUponTimeout(true).groupTimeout(2000)` Do we really need to again call `groupTimeout` even if we are using `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`

Comment: The `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` does its logic only when message arrives to the aggregator. The point of `groupTimeout()` to have some background task when there is no incoming message for the specific time.